# VMWare VM's get laggy and disk W/R is really slow

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, vmware

I'm having an issue with VMWare VM's where they get really laggy and disk Write/Read speeds get reaaaally slow when copying files from a network shared folder from my PC to the VM.
It seems that forcing power off and then reopening the VM fixes it, but sometimes it's running heavy tasks and can't just power it off...

The software I use to copy is FastCopy.

The specs given to the VM are fine:

- 8 physical cores from a 5950x
- 64GB 3600Mhz (128GB total in my physical system)
- 60GB NVMe (500GB NVMe, 130GB free)
- The shared folder is a VMWare Player shared folder which is in another NVMe (No errors in this NVMe either)
- Window 10 Pro with the latest updates
- VMWare Player 16.1
- Only this VM running

The max write speed from the NVMe is 1.5GB/s.
I'm copying over 9GB of data spread in about 400K files.
At some point, the VM becomes really slow and the copying drops from 280~ files/s to a stuck 60 Files/s but it's really copying like 1 file per 2-3 seconds...

I ran a test in Samsung Magician and there are not any errors on the NVMe...
Resetting the VM fixes it...

Ran a lot of tests over RAM, CPU Stress and check temps, NVMe has no errors, etc.
I think it's something with VMWare but can't find what is it...

What could be causing the problem?

***EDIT: I have always disabled Windows Defender all the time, to avoid problems while copying files.***

Comment: Make sure you are not giving too many resources to the VM. Not more than 1/2 the CPU resource - usually 1 CPU with 2 cores is enough. Probably 8GB of memory will be enough as well and if you need more, you can add.

Comment: Did the above solve your problem? It usually does.

Comment: @John Hello, no it didn't...
I tried making different combinations, from 16GB of RAM, 4GB, 8, etc.
It keeps present. Guess this may be something related to my installation of VMWare player